# VLC dotnet VlcMediaPlayer snapshot

Tags: c#, .net, video, vlc, snapshot

I am using C# to develop video list with 4 snapshot Win Software. VLC dotnet sound good to capture different video format snapshot.

I want to take 4 snapshot each video. Unfortunately, **player.GetMedia().Duration.TotalSeconds** is always -0.001 that means media has not set to the player.

But I use **player.play()** that is work and prompt a new form to play my video. How come?

I pull the Vlc dotnet from VS 2015 NuGet Package Manager. Less reference was found in internet so that ask for help in this platform. Hope anyone give me a hand.

Here is my code

```
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer player = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC"));
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMedia media = player.SetMedia(new System.IO.FileInfo(videoFullPath));
            double len = player.GetMedia().Duration.TotalSeconds;
            interval = (int)(len * 0.95) / 4;
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i + interval)
            {
                player.Position = i;
                counter++;
                player.TakeSnapshot(
                    new System.IO.FileInfo(
                        storagePath + "\\" + screenShotPrefix
                                 + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                                 + "\\screenshot_" + counter.ToString() + counter.ToString() + ".jpg"
                  ), 320, 240);
            }
```